# I want to find out which form of mahavidya to worship according to shaktism/tantra

Tags: astrology, tantra, shaktism, dasha-mahavidya

So I have read that in tantra or kula path, each person is given a specific form of maha vidya to worship ( By their gurus i think). I dont have a guru and I dont mean to do tantra without a guru but if I could find out the specific form of mahavidya I am suited to worship then atleast I could meditate on that form or something until or until not I find an actual guru. So can anyone tell me ways to find out which form is suited for each individual? maybe using kundali chart or something.

Comment: Anyone can do all Mahavidya start from easy ones - Sri Vidya.

Comment: I think you meant to say "not anyone can do mahavidya" . Well anyway then tell me how to do Sri Vidya do you know how?

Comment: To start with Sri Vidya, you need to take initiation (or diksha) from a reputed guru. There are some authentic Sri Vidya tradition pandits in south that have been giving openly initiation to everyone. Few of Kaula Schools in North too do the same.

Comment: Yes genius every one knows you need diksha. I meant do you know anyone, and I think you don't so thanks for nothing